# Defining constant in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm pretty new to Objective C and I want to define some constant based on the value of the other constant.

```
#define MODE_DEV YES
#if (MODE_DEV)
    #define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://dev.testurl.com";
#else
    #define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://prod.testurl.com";
#endif
```

And I'm using `WEBSERVICE_URL` as following.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@add_device_token", WEBSERVICE_URL]];
```

But I'm getting error in the above line.

The error says, `"Expected ]"`.

I have no idea what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon at the end of your `#define` lines.

Remember, a `#define` is just a textual substitution. So you are saying:

```
#define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://dev.testurl.com";
```

Thus the semicolon is part of the text substitution and gives nonsense in context:

```
NSURL *url = 
    [NSURL URLWithString:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%@add_device_token", @"http://dev.testurl.com";]];
                                                            ^
```

Comment: @user3300990 If my answer solved the problem, you are permitted to accept it (checkmark). This marks the issue as solved for other users, among other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

The key you should remember that `#define` is just **REPLACING TEXT** (always remember it)

exp:

```
#define something bySomethingElse...!@#$%^&*
```

Where you use `something`, xcode will replace it by `bySomethingElse...!@#$%^&*`

You should remove **";"**

Good luck

Comment: But that's the same as what I said.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't see your post when I press enter :(. OK, I will delete it

Answer (score 0):

No need of semicolon separator here.

```
#define MODE_DEV YES

#if (MODE_DEV)
#define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://dev.testurl.com"
#else
#define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://prod.testurl.com"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

There is how it's done:

```
#define MODE_DEV YES
#if (MODE_DEV)
    #define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://dev.testurl.com"
#else
    #define WEBSERVICE_URL @"http://prod.testurl.com"
#endif

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:WEBSERVICE_URL "/add_device_token"];
```